# Issue translating sentence from familia romana

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

The following sentence is of familia romana pars II:

Deinde, temporibus augusti, senatus populusque romanus aedem concordiae  vetustate collapsam in meliorem faciem restituit.

I would translate this as:
Then, in the times of augustus, the senate and the people of rome restored the collapsed temple of harmony in/to a better state.

As you can see I am missing the translation for 'vetustate' here. It being ablative and not accusative like 'aedem collapsam' confuses. How should I interpret this word in the context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Vetustate collapsam*, "collapsed because of age".

(In terms of textbook categories this might be described as an ablative of cause or an ablative of instrument, but those categories are rather artificial and tend to slip into each other.)